# In F#, do agent ReplyChannels/AsyncReplyChannels cross threads?

Tags: f#, agent

For example, if I start an agent (1) on a UI thread, then start another agent (2) on a background thread and send a message from (1) to (2) that includes a ReplyChannel/AsyncReplyChannel and then send a reply from (2) back to (1), is that enough to ensure cross-thread communication between a background-thread agent and the UI-thread agent? 
Other methods for communicating with an agent on a specific thread seem to prefer using the raising of events on the specific thread's SynchronizationContext, and say nothing about using ReplyChannels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u talk about agents do u mean mailboxprocessors?
In that case sending/posting messages and using replychanel is sufficient to communicate between two agents/threads.

Pls note that the communication will NOT happening between the UI thread and the background thread u mentioned directly. Each agent/mailboxprocessor has its own thread.

If u use "PostAndReply" from UI thread u don't need SynchronizationContext as the call is blocking internally.

If u use "PostAndAsyncReply" an async F# workflow will be returned. In that case u still need to use SynchronizationContext.
In that case pls refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.switchtocontext-method-%5Bfsharp%5D

Comment: so there exists a mechanism, like a dispatcher, for cross thread communication between agents (F#'s accepted alias for MailboxProcessor)? Yes I realize that direct, manual thread-to-thread communication in F# requires use of SynchronizationContext (SC), thats the point of my question: Does the use of ReplyChannel/AsyncReplyChannel obviate the need for specifying SC? thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully make it more precise

Comment: from Petricek's book section 16.5.2 Accessing mailbox concurrently
The mailbox processor handles only a single message at time, but it can be safely accessed from multiple threads. All the methods for posting message to the processor (such as Post and PostAndReply) are thread-safe.